# importing sql file into new database speed

Tags: mysql, sql, database

When I need to replicate my database from one machine to another I usually do
mysqldump -u root -ppassword database > backup.sql
then on the other machine
mysql -u root -ppassword databsae < backup.sql

However I am right now dealing with a 1 GB sql file and it is taking hours! are there any other ways to do this?

Comment: Is the 1GB file just one table?  Or many tables/databases?

Comment: dozens of tables for one database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, too many variables are missing from the question. Are the db datadir and the file on the same disk mount? Is the dump using an extended insert? (assuming no)

If a textual dump is the only solution (meaning you don't wanna use xtrabackup or an LVM snapshot) then you want to make you musqldump use extended insert (so one insert for each whole table, faster) and try to have the file on a separate mount from the data directory to reduce disk seeks. For that point on, it's all IO bound and the disk speed is your bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use HeidiSQL to manage my backups.  Once you have connections set in the tool you can backup from source1 to source2 quite quickly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows your data are at path like this:

> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\data

in there you will have folders with the names of your databases, you can copy and paste these folders to other computer and should work.

Answer (score 0):

Stop the servers, just copy archive and zip the fles in the db directory, do the reverse on the target machine. You'll need to square up permissions and such to the dbs on the new server. Copying the mysql database while doable could leave you in a bit of a mess.

This is not a backup though, don't use it as one, more like an image.